# convert large integeer to binary Little-Endian php

Tags: php, binary, pack, converters

I want convert 365 decimal to binary  (each number four bytes)
So i convert:

```
pack("s*",1); // output .... , in hexedidor: 01000000
```

And this is the correct output
But when conver 365 :

```
pack("s*",365); // output m... in hexeditr:6D000100
```

But I expect `6D010000`
How can I get that conclusion?
[example output I need
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61pTr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61pTr.jpg)

my code :

```
$content= pack("s*",365);
file_put_contents("file.txt",iconv("UTF-8","UTF-16LE",$content));
```

Comment: i am getting strange output like this `m` can  you show how you getting that binary string

Comment: you want binary conversion of BCD conversion??

Comment: I did not ask the question correctly and I've updated it now
I'm going to get out `6D010000` instead `6D000100` when number 365 becomes

Comment: Can you post the complete code @lock

Comment: Excuse me if I can not properly transfer the purpose
,I do not have a specific code, and I'm the ones that I put in question
I'm going to get  365 become like that example,
I added an image of the final output required for the question

Comment: Buddy you completely messed up `first` you are showing hex editor output or any other editor output `second` the out put you are telling in question is the hex editor value . use the below function `decbin` and then check your output and `last` please tell me what software you are using to see this output and how

Comment: when use decbin(365) output `310030003100310030003100310030003100` , The software I check `Hex Workshop` ,See what I'm going to do to write this number in the file and use it in c++,when there is an output file from c++ (this number) there is this `m...` and when open with hexeditor `6D010000` ,but when i write in file with php in hexeditor get this value `6D000100`

Comment: try to check the encoding in which you are writing the output before you reading it. Rest i am also checking new thing to learn great

Comment: My encoding write to file : UTF16

Comment: in updated code their is miss match in `$text` and `$content` kindly check